# Prevent overlapping axis label in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a bar chart with a logarithmic xAxis, where in some cases the axis labels overlap each other. Is there any way to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: This is the best I achieved: http://jsfiddle.net/dqkjrd7k/3/ - could you update my jsfiddle to get live demo, which we can used as bug-report? It should not happen.

Comment: @PawełFus updated the fiddle, the problem comes with font we are using: http://jsfiddle.net/dqkjrd7k/5/

Comment: @PawełFus and its get worse when you update the fiddle, initial rendering looks not that worst but if you change the fiddle and rerun it you get the same result as in the screen shot

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought - rendering font issue. I reported this [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4973) - thanks! How about simple workaround to make more space on ticks? For example setting `tickPixelInterval`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/dqkjrd7k/7/

Comment: Thanks that fixed it